# OptionsMenu onOptionsSelected gives me nothing

Tags: android, options-menu

I am trying to make a simple Activity which has a menu with two buttons. The first button will load a separate activity, while the second button I am leaving with nothing to do for now. I have put log statements everywhere but the only one which is executed is the one in onCreateOptionsMenu.

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set up window View
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Log.i( "onCreate", "veryBeginning" );
}

public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu ) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate( R.menu.option_menu, menu );
    Log.i( "onCreateOptionsMenu", "hereasd" );
    return true;
}

public boolean onOptionsSelected( MenuItem item ) {
    Log.i( "onOptionsSelected", "start" );
    switch( item.getItemId() ) {
    case R.id.connect:
        Log.i( "onOptionsSelected" , "r.id.connect" );
        startActivity( new Intent(getApplicationContext(), DeviceList.class ) );
        finish();
        return true;
    case R.id.preferences:
        Log.i( "onOptionsSelected" , "r.id.preferences" );
        return true;
    default:
        Log.i( "onOptionsSelected" , "r.id.?" );
        return super.onContextItemSelected( item );
    }
}
```

I start the program on my device, open the menu, and click both buttons numerous times, but none of the Logs are showing up in my LogCat.

This is my LogCat

```
06-13 14:11:34.643: I/onCreate(15262): veryBeginning
06-13 14:11:49.098: W/KeyCharacterMap(15080): No keyboard for id 0
06-13 14:11:49.098: W/KeyCharacterMap(15080): Using default keymap:/system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
06-13 14:11:49.098: I/onCreateOptionsMenu(15080): hereasd
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item)`. see [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onOptionsItemSelected%28android.view.MenuItem%29).